# Best Plugin in Wordpress to import Reports in EXCEL format

Tags: wordpress, report

Can anyone please suggest best Plugin in Wordpress to import Reports in EXCEL format like this.

**Name of Visitor    Number of user who visited the Page    Visited Page URL**

We don't want to use **AWStats Report Viewer** as it will not work for Windows Server.

Comment: try this https://wordpress.org/plugins/visitors-traffic-real-time-statistics/

Comment: @RameshPardhi hi, Ramesh. Thanks for replay. But it does not have option to import data in Excel format. WP Statistics Plugin is also not working for MS SQL. Can you please suggest another one.

Comment: If nothing works then ask your hosting provider. They can help you with that. Are you getting ANY ERROR AFTER INSTALLING PLUGIN OR AFTER ACTIVATING IT?

Comment: The Error I am getting is: The following plugin table(s) do not exist in the database, please re-run the install routine : wp_statistics_visitor, wp_statistics_visit, wp_statistics_exclusions, wp_statistics_historical, wp_statistics_useronline, wp_statistics_pages, wp_statistics_search. But as I checked in my Database these tables exists. But data is not reflecting on Dashboard.

Comment: Are you on windows server or NGINX or apache?